# Android - Fragment is added to container before the last Fragment is removed

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have a problem regarding `FragmentTransaction`. So I rely on `onDestroyView()` and `onStop()` in every `Fragment` to show or hide a toolbar in the bottom of activity. Here's how I do the transaction :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    .replace(R.id.activity_frame, fragment, tag)
    .addToBackStack(tag)
    .commit();
```

When I debug, it shows that the new `Fragment` goes through its `onCreateView()` before the replaced `Fragment` goes through `onDestroyView()` and `onStop()`.

This just happened recently, I realized that the toolbar was showing abnormal behavior and haven't had the chance to check it out till this morning. Any hint on this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour was changed in the support library a while ago, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230415

You can switch to the old behaviour like described in that thread:

> This is an intended behavior change. There is new functionality to optimize the operations and postpone fragment transitions and this is a side effect of that.
>
> You can disable fragment operation optimizations by calling FragmentTransaction.setAllowOptimization(false). This forces everything to happen in the proper order, but also disallows the operations from optimized.

Another approach would be to not rely on `onDestroyView()` and `onStop()` beeing called, but rather handling the already present toolbar in `onCreateView()` of the new Fragment. For example by always replacing the toolbar in `onCreateView()` and only removing the toolbar in `onStop()` / `onDestroy()` if the toolbar is still the one created by the own fragment.

Comment: Whoa so it is intended? I thought so but I downgraded my support library and it doesn't change anything, I guess I didn't downgrade enough.. Btw it's actually the same exact toolbar which the activity manages. I keep making it GONE in every fragment onDestroy or on stop so that it will only be used in that certain fragment, or any other fragment which needs it..

Comment: That makes it even simpler. You could control the visibility of the toolbar only in onCreateView() in an abstract base Fragment that defines an abstract boolean showToolbar() method for your fragments to implement. Just some brainstorming :)

Comment: Well, I've been doing that lol.. From that answer you gave, pointing out there's a new method in `FragmentTransaction` which is `.setAllowOptimization(false)` makes it all return to normal, thank you! And oops I haven't accepted your answer since yesterday, it was time for me to go somewhere else lol